# How to delete all in json server

Tags: json, angular, typescript, json-server

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) `json server` in my Angular app, to create, fetch, and delete posts.

In the following method, I delete a post with a specified id:

```
deleteConsumer(post: Post): Observable<Post> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${post.id}`;
    return this.httpClient.delete<Post>(url);
}
```

I looked at the `.delete` code and searched for something like a `.deleteall` but could not find it. Is there really no such method that would delete everything?

If there really isn't, then my attempt at doing it myself is not paying off, because what I have done is not working:

```
deleteConsumers(): Observable<Post> {   
    let i: number = 0;
    this.httpClient.get<Post[]>(this.apiUrl).forEach(
      () => {
        ++i;
        const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${i}`;
        return this.httpClient.delete<Post>(url);
      }
    );
}
```

Obviously, this is wrong in terms of return type, but I cannot figure out what to do... How can I modify the first method, so it would go through all the json objects in my `db.json` file; meaning iterate through all the existing posts and delete them all?

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete all objects with provided number?

Comment: @navnath No, I wanna delete all objects (with whatever ID) not just a specific one with a specific ID.

Comment: try this `http.delete("path/id1,id2")`

Comment: @navnath Thank you, This is useful, I will try it. But does it mean I will have to add all the IDs I wanna delete? What if there is loads? Is there any way of looping over them using the same syntax?

Comment: As i know there is no feature in json-server to delete all objects at once.

Comment: @navnath I see... So, that's why I couldn't find such a method. Thanks for your answer. I will use the concatenated IDs then.

Comment: Share here if concatenated id approach works

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did encounter this when using json-server with Vue.js and I realized that there was no special function to delete all at once. I had to work around it.

So, for example in your case, I would first map the posts array to get a new array with only the post ids:

```
const postsIdsArray = this.posts.map((post) => post.id)
```

Then, assuming you already have a function to delete one post given the id, I would then execute the function for each of the ids in the array:

```
postsIdsArray.forEach((id) => this.deletePost(id))
```

Just combine the two lines in one JavaScript function (in this case I used Vue.js):

```
deleteAllPosts(){
   const postsIdsArray = this.posts.map((post) => post.id)
   postsIdsArray.forEach((id) => this.deletePost(id))
}
```